# Problems overloading [] operator with a template class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm having problems overloading the subscript operator with a template class in c++. I have a custom map class implementation and I need to be able to access the elements via the key.

```
template <typename K, typename DT>
DT& myMap<K, DT>::operator[](K key)
{
  for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
 {
    if (elements[i].key == key){
        return elements[i].data;
    }
 } 
}
```

Is how I'm trying to overload the operator at the moment. The compiler doesn't accept the K key to search for the data. K being the data type for the key. This is stored in a separate class that the myMap class contains in an array.

So if in main I try to do:

```
myMap<string, int> * test = new myMap < string, int > ;
test["car"] = 50;
```

It says:

```
Error expression must have an integral or unscoped enum type
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: Why not just use `myMap<string, int> test;` and then `test["car"]` will work as expected.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `new` unnecessarily, which is a bad habit that should be avoided in C++. This is not Java or C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`test` is a pointer to `MyMap`, not an object thereof, so `test["car"]` is calling the built-in dereference operator, not your overload.

You need `(*test)["car"]` or `test->operator[]("car")` to make it work.

Comment: No this is not the best answer. Yes, this makes the code work, but does not fix "the problem"! The problem is not that the code does not compile, but that the OP unnecessarily used a pointer and heap allocation!

Comment: @FabioFracas yeah, that makes my answer useless. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you use a pointer to `MyMap` instead of the Object itself. Instead of

```
myMap<string, int> * test = new myMap < string, int > ;
(*test)["car"] = 50 // works but is not idiomatic C++
// ...
delete test; // don't forget!
```

you should use

```
auto test = myMap<string, int>{}; 
// or: myMap<string, int> test = myMap<string, int>{};
test["car"] = 50
```

If you really need to use pointers, you should at least use smart pointers:

```
auto test_ptr = std::make_unique<myMap<string, int>>();
// or: std::unique_ptr<myMap<string, int>> test_ptr = std::make_unique<myMap<string, int>>();
(*test)["car"] = 50;
```